# Word 2007 displaying {FORMTEXT} in place of forms

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-office-2007

My friend is suffering from an issue in Word 2007. All the files with a form open incorrectly, with all the form fields replaced with {FORMTEXT}. I opened the same files in Word 2010 and they open perfectly on my computer. Exporting to PDF from the same Word 2007 makes the forms appear perfectly in the PDF.

**Can you tell my what kind of setting makes her Word 2007 not show the forms correctly?**

Comment: I updated my answer.  Sorry, the previous one was for printing.  This one should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a field code issue.  Use ALT&F9 to toggle "show file codes" or you can do this with word options like so 'Office Button|Word Options|Advanced > Show Document Content' as discussed [here](http://help.wugnet.com/office/ALT-F9-work-100-ftopict1104242.html).

For printing try [this](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/725791.html):

Go to File / Print / Options

"Include with Document":

Clear the "Field Codes" check box

OK / Close

Best of luck...